# JS variable.new What does it mean?

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer-8

```
function controlPackage(action, row, txt, params) 
{
    alert("STOP1");
    clearTimeout(pollClientTableTimer);
    if ( confirm(txt.confirm) ) 
    {
        showActivityBar(txt.activity);
        $.getJSON("ajax_requests/controlPackage.php",
        { 
            id: params.pkg_id, 
            date: params.activate_date, 
            'action': action, 
            'new': params.new 
        },
        function(data)
        {
            var is_error = data.code == 400 ? 1 : 0;
            pollClientTable(pollClientTableTimerPoll, false);
            var msg = data.message;
            for ( var i in data.errors ) 
            {
                msg += "<br/>\u2022 "+data.errors[i];
            }
            closeActivityBar();
            setMessage(msg, is_error);
        });
    } 
    else 
    {
        pollClientTable(pollClientTableTimerPoll, true);
    }
}
```

I have this function, that was developed before I took over the product, What i am unclear about is what params.new means.

The reason for asking this is because I am getting an Expected Identifier error in IE8 pointing to this line in the code.

params is a JSON ENCODE:

```
$params = $json->encode(array("pkg_id"=>$clientPackage->getId(), "activate_date"=>$clientPackage->getActivationDate()));
```

So what I'm asking is what does the params.new mean and why is it throwing this error.

Comment: `params.new` is just a property called `new` on the `params` object.

Comment: `new` is a reserved word. You'd likely be better off using a different name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params.new` is just a property (an unfortunately named one at that) called `new` on the `params` object.

You should access it using `params["new"]` to avoid the error. The name `new` is problematic since it's the [name of an operator in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).

If you have control over the name of the property, I would recommend changing it.

Answer (score 0):

`params` seems to be a JSON object, which has different properties (eg. activate_date, action, new).